# Saving matplotlib animation takes too long

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general, but I still hope my issue can be fixed since I haven't found a sufficient answer up until now.

My basic exercise is to create a small animation of the orbits of earth and jupiter based on a given fictional dataset. This animation is very basic(meaning basically some colored balls moving in circles).

Now, I've used the matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation module to create the animation, and it worked very good and as intended. The problem occurs when I try to save the animation. The saving process if far slower than the originally created animation and gets slower the further it progresses, almost coming to a complete stop short way into the task.

Now my guess is that since the dataset is very big(10000 points) and the save(...) continuously layers frames on top of each other, it rapidly becomes too much to handle for the program.

This is about as far as I got until now but I haven't found anything to resolve the issue. Again, my knowledge of programming is quite limited but I still hope there is a solution.

NOTE: this code would require the specified "orbits.out" file to run. I can try to make this available as well but maybe there isn't a necessity for this.

I use Anaconda on Windows 10 and code with Microsoft Visual Studio Code (if that's relevant)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation as ani

#read out basic information before reading out the data set
fileHandle = open("orbits.out")
basedata = fileHandle.read(41) #41
fileHandle.close()

#numpy array with the columns: t xSun ySun xEarth yEarth xJupiter yJuptier
dataset = np.loadtxt("orbits.out", skiprows = 5, 
                usecols = (0,1,2,4,5,7,8))

#create a image with the starting positions for all points
fig, grid = plt.subplots()

sun_data = [dataset[0,1], dataset[0,2]]
earth_data = [dataset[0,3], dataset[0,4]]
jupiter_data = [dataset[0,5], dataset[0,6]]

#create separate elements to use different colors and sizes
sun, = grid.plot(sun_data[0], sun_data[1], "yo", 
            markersize = 20,  animated = True,
            label = "Sun")
earth, = grid.plot(earth_data[0], earth_data[1], "bo", 
            markersize = 10,  animated = True,
            label = "Earth")
jupiter, = grid.plot(jupiter_data[0], jupiter_data[1], "mo", 
            markersize = 15,  animated = True,
            label = "Jupiter")
grid.legend(loc = "upper left")

def init():

    grid.set_xlim(-6.5, 6.5)
    grid.set_ylim(-6.5, 6.5)

return sun, earth, jupiter, 

def system(frame):

    f = frame
    print("step number:", f)

    #update the positions
    sun.set_data(dataset[f,1], dataset[f,2])
    earth.set_data(dataset[f,3], dataset[f,4])
    jupiter.set_data(dataset[f,5], dataset[f,6])

return sun, earth, jupiter,

draw = ani(fig, system, frames = np.arange(1, len(dataset[:,0])),
        init_func = init, blit = True, interval = 30, 
        repeat_delay = 0)

plt.show()

draw.save("orbits.gif", writer = "imagemagick")
```

Comment: How large is your dataset? Maybe you don't have enough memory to write the complete gif file at once?

Comment: The part of the dataset used should create ~10000 frames and contains x and y coordinates for each of the 3 plotted points per frame. I'm not sure if it can be safe all at once but the program hasn't gotten this far yet since it slows down drastically at ~2000 frames created.

Comment: If that many frames are needed, don't try to create an animated gif. This is probably the most inefficient way to create video.

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you have any thoughts on how to create the video in a more efficient way ?

Comment: Most people would create a mp4 video, as also shown in [the example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html).

Comment: Ah yes I've tried part of this already, but the saving as .mp4 had the same problem

Comment: Try using the [`FFMpegFileWriter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FFMpegFileWriter.html#matplotlib.animation.FFMpegFileWriter) instead.